# ClearAll except a data table

Tags: syntax, variable-definitions, attributes, clear

How can I `ClearAll` variables and tables, except a table of data? Suppose the data table is `WRR`.

```
WRR = Table[WRR[i] = Last[m[i] /. aRR], {i, 10}];
```

I am looking for something like:

```
Protect[WRR]; ClearAll...
```

But this removes `WRR` too!

Comment: How could it work, `ClearAll` alone does not do anything. Does this work: ``(ClearAll["Global`*"]; WRR = #) &@WWR``?

Comment: `ClearAll @@ Cases[Names["Global`*"], Except["WRR"]]`

Answer (score 3):

I think the attribute you are looking for is [`Locked`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locked.html).

```
WRR = Range[10];
x = 5;

SetAttributes[WRR, Locked];
```

Now:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

x

WRR
```

> ClearAll::locked: Symbol WRR is locked. >>
>
> ```
> x
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

You can still redefine `WRR` as it is not [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html):

```
WRR = {11, 12, 13};

WRR
```

> ```
> {11, 12, 13}
> ```

To clear its definition use [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html):

```
WRR =.;

WRR
```

> ```
> WRR
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments:

```
(ClearAll["Global`*"]; WRR = #) & @ WWR
```

or

```
ClearAll @@ Cases[Names["Global`*"], Except["WRR"]]
```

or

```
ClearAll @@ DeleteCases[Names["Global`*"], "WRR"]
```

etc.